# Selenium (Java): hover over a button and click on either of the options

Tags: java, css, selenium, mousehover

I am using Selenium to automate a UI using Java language.

I have an action button and when the User hover overs the mouse on Action button, it gives two clickable options - Create and Edit

I have stored CSS locators as Enums for Action button and also for Create and Edit (clickable) links as ACTIONBUTTON, CREATEACTION, EDITACTION respectively.

I used a Java code like below but it gives an error saying *java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement*

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement((WebElement) DCSAdminEnums.ACTIONBUTTON.getLocator());

actions.moveToElement((WebElement) DCSAdminEnums.CREATEACTION.getLocator());
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Please suggest you can help a better way to handle this, using the Enums that I have.

UPDATE: 
I also tried with the below style of code but it did not work :-(

```
WebElement menu = driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='button-1177-btnInnerEl']")));
WebElement submenu = driver.findElement((By.cssSelector("a[id='menuitem-1175-itemEl']")));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
action.click(submenu).perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`By` and `WebElement` are different type, hence the compilation error.

If you are talking about actions are not performed, then that's a totally different thing from your original post. Please ask a new question.

`WebbElement` can be retrieved by `driver.findElement(By locator)`, so you need to use `driver.findElement(yourLocator)` to get element first.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(DCSAdminEnums.ACTIONBUTTON.getLocator()));
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(DCSAdminEnums.CREATEACTION.getLocator()));
actions.click().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work for me :-(
I even tried writing the below style (without using the Enums) but still no luck..

    WebElement menu = driver.findElement((By.xpath("//*[@id='button-1177-btnInnerEl']")));
    WebElement submenu = driver.findElement((By.cssSelector("a[id='menuitem-1175-itemEl']")));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(menu).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    action.click(submenu).perform();

Comment: Sorry for that vague response from me. I think I am having trouble with identifying the exact CSS/XPATH locator and/or also the submenu item is not being visible to Selenium. But as you said, its a different question.
Thanks again :-)